# americanpurpose1 Font family shows smiley on using Special character like ( and # etc

Tags: html, css, font-family

I have used the `americanpurpose1` font family for my project but it shows Smiley on using special Characters like () , # etc. I have also tried HTML symbol codes but this does not work. Here's my code:

```css
.login_heading h2 {
  margin: 20px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 31px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #0d0831;
  font-family: americanpurpose1;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="login_heading">
  <h2>Top 100 Graded Comics Sold</h2>
  <h2 id="changedate">( Last 1 Week )</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your code, expected output and actual output.

Comment: I have added my code now @JimGarrison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is characteristic of the font in question.
The font display these emoticons replacing `()` and `#` default.
The only alternative is change the font.

[image: Picture]

Here you have another alternative font, pretty similar:

[image]

[**-- Passion One - Google Font**](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Passion+One)